# Why I do not see obj and mtl in this A-frame?

Tags: html, aframe, .obj, webvr

I am just getting started with a-frame 0.4.0 3d objects, but I think I make something basic wrong.
I started as I see here: https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/components/obj-model.html
 and I used this model: http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/wood-texture-created-in-cycles-82780.html But this doesn't worked for me. Why? How can I do well?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>objtest</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="tree-obj" src="WoodTexture.obj"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="tree-mtl" src="WoodTexture.mtl"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>
      <a-entity obj-model="obj: #tree-obj; mtl: #tree-mtl"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you use `aframe.js`? if not, try it. rename `.obj` and '.mtl' file without space. I have tried this model file, it works for me.

Comment: Thanks! Is it normal to see without texture? I renamed the .mtl file too, and the model is gray.  I created a screenshot here: http://imgur.com/a/wlCSA  Why?

Comment: Yes, you can look into this `.mtl` file, the file doesn't use any texture pictures. this model made by Blender and export to `.obj` type. the reason why it shows without texture you can see [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures), you can choose another suitable model.